# Statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or punctuation is incorrect

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am getting the following error for the code below :

> Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is
>   misspelled or missing or punctuation is incorrect.

I can't find  misspellings or reserved words I used, so I am thinking some sort of punctuation is missing or incorrect.  Since I am new at this, I am having trouble figuring it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The specific part of the code that I am getting the error on is

```vb
strMakePaTablesSQL = "SELECT [all vendor Rebates].[Key_Code_Name] as [Supplier Name], [all vendor Rebates].[Vendor_Name], " _
                   & "       [all vendor Rebates].[Contract_ID], [all vendor Rebates].[EXP_DATE], " _
                   & "       [all vendor Rebates].[Contract_Status], [all vendor Rebates].[Price Book Priority] as [High Priority Customer], " _
                   & "       [all vendor Rebates].[GPO Or biosite] as [GPO Indicator],  " _
                   & "       [all vendor Rebates].[LTM_Rebate_Dollars] as [LTM Rebate Dollars] " _
                   & " into [" & strTableName & "] From [all vendor Rebates] " _
                   & " Where [Vendor_Name] = '" & strSupplier & "'"

dbPa.Execute strMakePaTablesSQL
```

---

Full code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim dbXL As DAO.Database
Dim strDate As String
Dim strGenl As String
Dim strTableName As String
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strGroupPASQL As String
Dim strMakePaTablesSQL As String
Dim StrPaID As String
Dim strGenl2 As String
Dim strSupplier As String
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Function MakeTableVN()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim dbPa As DAO.Database
Dim rstIePa As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngTotRecCount As Long
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strADR_Name As String
Dim VN_Length As Double

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCreate_Local_Supplier_Contact_table"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAdd_New_Vendors_to_tblSupplierContact"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdate_Supplier_Contact_List"


Set dbPa = CurrentDb


strGroupPASQL = "SELECT [all vendor rebates].Vendor_Name FROM [all vendor rebates] GROUP BY [all vendor rebates].Vendor_Name "

Set rstIePa = dbPa.OpenRecordset(strGroupPASQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rstIePa
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveLast
        lngTotRecCount = .RecordCount
        .MoveFirst

        Do While Not .EOF

            strSupplier = .Fields("Vendor_Name") & ""

            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, ".", " ")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, ":", " ")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, "=", " ")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, "/", " ")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, "\", " ")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, "'", "")
            strSupplier = Replace(strSupplier, "*", " ")

            strTableName = strSupplier

            For Each tdf In dbPa.TableDefs
                If tdf.Name = strTableName Then
                    dbPa.TableDefs.Delete tdf.Name
                End If
            Next

           strMakePaTablesSQL = "SELECT [all vendor Rebates].[Key_Code_Name] as [Supplier Name], [all vendor Rebates].[Vendor_Name], " _
                                  & "[all vendor Rebates].[Contract_ID], [all vendor Rebates].[EXP_DATE], [all vendor Rebates].[Contract_Status], [all vendor Rebates].[Price Book Priority] as [High Priority Customer], [all vendor Rebates].[GPO Or biosite] as [GPO Indicator], [all vendor Rebates].[LTM_Rebate_Dollars] as [LTM Rebate Dollars] into [" & strTableName & "] From [all vendor Rebates] Where [Vendor_Name] = '" & strSupplier & "'"

            dbPa.Execute strMakePaTablesSQL

           Debug.Print "C:\Testing\Expiring rebates\Vendor_Files\" & strSupplier & ".xls"
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTableName, "C:\Testing\Expiring rebates\Vendor_Files\" & strSupplier & ".xls", True

            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strTableName
```

Comment: When is the error each time it's used?  What does the SQL evaluate to, what is `strMakePaTablesSQL ` just before the excecute?

Comment: Why are you stripping characters from what appears to be your primary key? `strSupplier` is quoted, so the only one that should matter is `'`.  I'd suggest using a parameterized statement so you don't have to worry about this. If you insist on the concat, escape it to `''` instead of removing it.

Comment: Also, no need to extract the vendor name is there as `[Vendor_Name] = '" & strSupplier & "'"`

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 0):

Yet, again a classic need to use parameterization, the industry best practice when running SQL at the application layer, here being VBA, but concept is transferable to most other languages. Specifically, consider [MS Access' QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) for your make-table process which does not need to have a different tailored name and parameterize the value in `WHERE` clause.

Below uses stored Access queries (more efficient than VBA string queries) that are referenced in VBA.

**SQL** *(save as query object: mySavedParamQuery)*

`PARAMETERS` clause is compliant only in Access SQL dialect.

```sql
PARAMETERS paramSupplier TEXT(255);
SELECT v.[Key_Code_Name] as [Supplier Name], v.[Vendor_Name],
       v.[Contract_ID], v.[EXP_DATE],
       v.[Contract_Status], v.[Price Book Priority] as [High Priority Customer],
       v.[GPO Or biosite] as [GPO Indicator], 
       v.[LTM_Rebate_Dollars] as [LTM Rebate Dollars]
INTO tmpVendorTable
FROM [all vendor Rebates] v
WHERE v.[Vendor_Name] = paramSupplier;
```

**SQL**  *(save as query object: mySavedAggregateQuery)*

```sql
SELECT v.Vendor_Name
FROM [all vendor rebates] v
GROUP BY v,Vendor_Name
```

---

**VBA** *(no SQL shows)*

```vb
...
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim strFile As String           

Set rstIePa = dbPa.OpenRecordset("mySavedAggregateQuery", dbOpenDynaset)
With rstIePa
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveLast
        lngTotRecCount = .RecordCount
        .MoveFirst

        Do While Not .EOF    
          strSupplier = .Fields("Vendor_Name")
          strFile = "C:\Testing\Expiring rebates\Vendor_Files\" & strSupplier & ".xls"

          For Each tdf In dbPa.TableDefs
             If tdf.Name = "tmpVendorTable" Then
                 dbPa.TableDefs.Delete tdf.Name
             End If
          Next tdf   

          Set qdef = dbPa.QueryDefs("mySavedParamQuery")   ' INITIALIZE QUERYDEF
          qdef!paramSupplier = strSupplier                 ' BIND PARAMETER
          qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                       ' EXECUTE ACTION  

          Debug.Print strFile
          DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                                    "tmpVendorTable", strFile, True    
          .MoveNext
       Loop
    End If
End With
```